# Data Loading again while navigating between Routes - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have an issue while loading data in tables. Actually,I have multiple components in my project. While navigating among routes back/forward again API calls are happening and again data is loading.

How can I set data without reload very time on navigation.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Handle your data loading with services. Services live outside of the component and only reload the data if you your route changes.

Documentation: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Well, but services alone probably won't fix Rajesh's problem. Because if the service makes a API call every time when the component wants to have the data, then a API call is made every time when the user navigates. There must be some kind of caching, maybe with a ngx store or simply a variable in the service.

Comment: Agreed, but his problem currently is, that a component gets completely loaded / unloaded when he  changes routes. The Documentation provides samples how this could be handled but kinda feels out of scope of the answer.